# How can the nmap tool be used to evade a firewall/IDS?

Tags: firewalls, ids, nmap

Some techniques are used to secure the operating system against network attacks e.g.: firewalls, antivirus software, an IDS like [SNORT](https://www.snort.org/), etc. To take advantage of the `nmap` tool, is it possible to deceive the intrusion detection system by evading detection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are various ways that comes handy with `nmap` to evade the basic Firewall rules or Intrusion Detection Systems (IDS).

1. **Packet Fragmentation:**

   - This option evade pattern matching detection technique. Since packet reassembly can be quite processor intensive, it's common for admin to disable it.
   - In snort, fragmentation reassembly functionality is disabled by default.
   - Usage:

     ```
     nmap -f <other options>
     ```
2. **Decoy Scan:**

   - We can add some random hosts either from the attacker's subnet or from victim's subnet while scanning the target.
   - In firewall logs, there will be multiple hosts along with the attacker's IP making it difficult to trace the attacker.
   - Usage:

     ```
     nmap -D <ip1, ip2,...,ME> <other options>
     ```
3. **Spoof source IP address:**

   - Attacker can spoof the source IP address (from the victim's subnet) so that it'll appear to IDS/firewall that it's legitimate user and will be passed.
   - Usage:

     ```
     nmap -S <spoofed ip> <other optins>
     ```
4. **Spoof source port:**

   - Attacker can spoof the source port no. while scanning the target to bypass the rules in the firewall that allow requests from few ports (ex. Port 53).
   - Usage:

     ```
     nmap --source-port <port no> <other options>
     ```
5. **Scanning Timing:**

   - There are various timing options included in the nmap to send successive packets. It can be used to evade some of the rules in the firewalls or IDS.

     - T0: Paranoid (Waits 5 minutes between sending each probes, not detected by IDS/IPS)
     - T1: Sneaky (waits 15 seconds)
     - T2:Polite
     - T3:Normal
     - T4:Aggressive
     - T5:Insane (easily detectable)
   - Usage:

     ```
     nmap -T<0-5> <other options>
     ```

There are other options like Data-length appending and Badsum which can also be used. **IDLE Scan** is the best that I'll suggest for evading the firewall.
Although, all the methods mentioned above claim to evade the firewall/IDS, but if rules are set properly your scan can still be detected.

Answer (score 2):

Nmap has several useful options which can help you evade a firewall/IDS. The effectiveness of these options will depend upon what you are up against, i.e. the system(s) and how they are configured. A properly configured, modern firewall will hinder your scans very effectively.

A good breakdown of the nmap options you can use can be found [here](https://nmap.org/book/man-bypass-firewalls-ids.html). Generally speaking you're trying to change the traffic sent by Nmap in a way which causes the firewall/IDS you're up against to miss it.

**Edit**

A note on decoys (as requested in comment below). The Nmap `-D` option allows you to specify a list of decoy IP addresses, for example (`192.168.1.1` as the target):

```
nmap -D 192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3,192.168.1.4 192.168.1.1
```

There's also the ability to generate some random IP's as decoys:

```
nmap -D RND:5 192.168.1.1
```

Note that there's several caveats with using `-D`; such as the risk of SYN flooding your target, ISPs not forwarding spoofed packets, and only being available using specific Nmap scans. Hope that helps!